# if statement and greater than comparison in a single mySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

Table S1

```
SELECT  
    IF(
       IF( 
       ISNULL(S1.ACTUAL_END_DATE),S1.AGREED_END_DATE, S1.ACTUAL_END_DATE
    ) > S1.AGREED_END_DATE, 1, O)
```

From Table;

Description:- I need AGREED_END_DATE if ACTUAL_END_DATE is null. Otherwise ACTUAL_END_DATE. Then check whether that value is greater than AGREED_END_DATE. If so print 1, if not 0.

But there seems to be a problem in the query. So guys could you please help me out here. Appreciate it :)

Comment: Using COALESCE might be simpler than IF

Comment: But as this is purely a SQL issue, why tag it as `php` and not `sql` or whatever flavour of database you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I think you intend the following logic:

```
select (coalesce(S1.ACTUAL_END_DATE, S1.AGREED_END_DATE) > S1.AGREED_END_DATE)
```

That's it.  No `if` or `case` is needed in MySQL because booleans are treated as integers.

You could also write this as:

```
select (S1.ACTUAL_END_DATE > S1.AGREED_END_DATE AND S1.ACTUAL_END_DATE IS NOT NULL)
```